# Replicate Rails Admin HABTM with 2 selects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'd like to replicate this form element in my rails app, I have a model that I'm categorizing with multiple categories and I would like to do with via 2 select boxes but I have no idea how to accomplish it I have tried it with different thing but can't seem to get it. Anyone have an idea of how to accomplish this funcionality or a tutorial?

Here is the form I'm talking about. Specifically the one for teams/fans. Keep in my that my associations are correct it's just the view that overwhelms me.

http://rails-admin-tb.herokuapp.com/admin/team/new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, for example

```
f.collection_select 'tax_ids', @taxes, :id, :name, {:name => 'line_item[tax_ids][]'}
```

or

```
<%= collection_select :user, :role_ids, Role.find(:all, :order => 'name ASC'), :id, :name, { :selected => @user.role_ids }, { :multiple => true, :name => 'user[role_ids][]' } -%>
```

The :selected option should be in the last option hash, at least in recent versions of Rails. Also, if working with a form_for or fields_for object (f) you can skip the :name option, it seems to be set appropriately. There's no need for accepts_nested_attributes_for - this should work out of the box with a has_and_belongs_to_many relation. Example view code: = `f.collection_select :delivery_method_ids, DeliveryMethod.inactive, :id, :to_s_with_price, {}, { :selected => @user.delivery_method_ids, :multiple => true }`

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just a kind of select_multiple? If what you want is to be able to do a select over related objects, use a standard collection_select ( http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select )

```
collection_select(:post, :fan_ids, Fan.all, :id, :name, {}, :multiple => true)
```

You will get a standard list where you can select with Ctrl-click any number of Fans (or whatever related item)

If what you want is the actual user interface of rails_admin, then look at their code to know what to write.